# How to filter gmail messages by sender and not display the ones by others in the same thread

Tags: email, gmail, filtering

Gmail's default behaviour, when filtering received emails by sender, is to show all messages in the thread to which a sender responded, including messages by other senders. This is especially annoying when many people take part in discussion. Is it possible to display messages literally only by a specific sender in gmail and hide other in the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way is to turn off threads completely in configuration options.